# Access parent attribute in independent nested model view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have nested resources

```
 resources :invoices do
  resources :payments
 end
```

The invoices model is as follows:

```
 class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :invoices
attr_accessible :due_date, :invoice_date, :reading_ids, :customer_id, :customer, :status, :amount, :balance

has_many :invoice_items, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :payments, :dependent => :destroy
 end
```

The payments model is as follows:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :amount, :method, :payment_date, :reference_no, :invoice_id
 belongs_to :invoice
end
```

The payments controller is as follows:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def new
    invoice = Invoice.find(params[:invoice_id])
    @payment = invoice.payments.build
respond_to do |format|
  format.html #new.html.erb 
end 
  end
    end
```

I have created a view to record new payments and would like to display the customer details (name in particular) in this view, how do i go about it?

Payments view

```
<%= simple_form_for [@payment.invoice, @payment], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @payment %>

<h5> Invoice Details </h5>
<%= f.input :invoice_id,  disabled: true,  as: :string %>
<%= f.input :method, as: :select, :collection => [['Cash','Cash'],['Cheque','Cheque'],['In-House transfer','In-House transfer'],['Account Ledger','Account ledger']], :selected => ['Cash','Cash'] %>
  <%= f.input :reference_no, as: :string %>
  <%= f.input :payment_date, as: :string, input_html: { class: "datepicker" } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
<%= @payment.invoice.customer.name %>
```

anywhere in the view.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. One more question, how about accessing the balance from the invoice model and displaying it in the payments view as a default value under "Amount received" element, do i use @payment.invoice.balance

Comment: You're welcome. Exactly, using `@payment.invoice.balance` should work. You can mark your question as answered.